# Using $state.go in $http response interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to do a state navigation when receiving a forbidden or an unauthorized http request using http interceptors, but I'm receiving an error on the $state.go promise

`Error: transition superseded`

This is my responseError interceptor:

```
angular.module('starter')

.factory('httpResponseInterceptor', function($injector) {
    return {
        responseError: function(errorResponse) {

            var loginParams = {
                info: true,
                reason: 'Please login.',
                title: errorResponse.data
            };
            var $state = $injector.get('$state');

            switch (errorResponse.status) {
                case 403:
                    $state.go('login', loginParams).then(function() {}, function(res) {
                        console.log(res);
                    });
                    break;
                case 401:
                    $injector.get('$state').go('login', loginParams);
                    break;
            }

            return errorResponse;
        }
    };
});
```

Is there any way to use the interceptor in this case?
Wrapping a timeout around the $state.go will do the trick though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you are probably already in a state transition, but the error interceptor kicks in and then you try to do another transition.

I always explicitly reject the currently resolving promise which is caught by the error interceptor:

instead of doing `return errorResponse;` you should inject `$q`service in the interceptor and do `return $q.reject(errorResponse);`

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not the interceptor's job to do UI actions. There should be an AuthService/Provider/Controller where you should send the data caught by the interceptor and based on that data, take the required action there. You could use either the events system or invoke a method inside the service.

This might not solve your problem but it will solve your future challenges.

Greetings from Cluj.

Answer (score 0):

@FlorianTopf said, that you are probably already in a state transition. You may consider  **$stateChangeError** event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
            console.log(event, toState, fromState, error);
            if (something) {
                $state.go('error', toParams, {
                    reload: false
                });
            }
        });
```